# Bar chart labeled with % relative to the Months in X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
     month = month.name[1:6],
     shirts = runif(6, min=1000, max=2000),
     hats = runif(6, min=1000, max=2000)
    ) |>
    pivot_longer(cols=c("shirts", "hats"), names_to="category", values_to="income")

df
```

The data frame:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   month    category income
   <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
 1 January  shirts    1782.
 2 January  hats      1489.
 3 February shirts    1094.
 4 February hats      1954.
 5 March    shirts    1467.
 6 March    hats      1483.
 7 April    shirts    1512.
 8 April    hats      1890.
 9 May      shirts    1600.
10 May      hats      1914.
11 June     shirts    1333.
12 June     hats      1609.
```

In order to create a bar plot with the income percentages relative for each category in each month, I did this:

```
df |> 
    group_by(month, category) |>
    summarize(income = sum(income, na.rm=TRUE)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x=month,y=income, fill=category)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=paste0(percent(income/sum(income)))), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), angle = 90, hjust=-0.1) +
    labs(x="Month",y="Income") +
    ylim(0, 4000)
```

But it is calculating the [percentage relative to the total income sum from january to june](https://freeimage.host/i/HMGVKPe).

I'd like this percentage to be relative to each month total income sum.

What could I change or add something new to the plot code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use monthly totals as the denominator, you need to compute your percentages while grouped by `month`. The data is still grouped by `month` after your `summarize()`, so add a `mutate()` there:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df |> 
    group_by(month, category) |>
    summarize(income = sum(income, na.rm=TRUE)) |>
    mutate(pct_label = percent(income/sum(income), accuracy = 0.1)) |>
    ungroup() |>
    ggplot(aes(x=month,y=income, fill=category)) +
    geom_col(position="dodge") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = pct_label), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), angle = 90, hjust=-0.1) +
    labs(x="Month",y="Income") +
    ylim(0, 4000)
```

[image]

Also note that `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: It has worked! Thank you. But why did you use "ungroup()" before creating the plot? I tried whithout it and the result was the same.

Comment: Honestly just persnicketiness on my part — I like to ungroup when I’m done with grouped operations, but you’re right that it’s unnecessary here.